# A-Law wave file conversion source code

Tags: audio, file-conversion

I need to translate A-Law companded files to regular un-companded PCM.  Is there any source code out there I can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [AlawCodec.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/media/sound/AlawCodec.java.html). 
The interesting things are in the static block of the class where the decoding tables are initialized and the `read` method.